# java divisor finding takes unlimited time

Tags: java

I've started my friend's school task as practicing, but I stucked at one point. I think my code is right, but definitely not if I see the result.
My problem is the following. The program has to go from 1 to a natural number, and find the least number which has that number of divisors as the current number.
for example: [1;1], [2;2], [3;4], [4;6], [5;16], [6;12]
because the 12 is the least number which has 6 divisor.
Extra requirement is to find all the 100 divisor-number pair in approx. 5 minutes on a standard, not too fast, not too slow PC.
But if I run the code, it stuck at the 23th number, and couldn't go further.
I've tried to shorten the operation number with a condition (if the current number has more divisor than what currently need, it breaks the loop), but it doesn't make any difference, and I don't know why couldn't find the right number and go on.
I would be grateful if Somebody could help me.
Thanks in advance!

```
public static String message (int numb){
    String[] messages = new String[4];
    messages[0] = "Working...";
    messages[1] = "Done!";
    messages[2] = "Please give the interval! [1-100]";
    return messages[numb];
}
public static int intervIn (){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inter = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    return inter;
}
public static int finding (int need){
    int divisor = 1;
    int out=1;
    if (need!=1){
        for (;out<2147483647;){
            for (int i = 2;i<=out/2;i++){
                if (out%i!=0){
                    }
                else {
                   divisor++;
                   if (divisor>=need){
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }
            divisor++;
            if (divisor==need){
                break;
            }
            else {
                divisor=1;
                out++;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
public static int[][] doit (int row, int column){
    int[][] arrayN = new int[row][column];
    int divisorNeed = 1;
    for (int k = 0;k<row;k++){
        arrayN[k][0]=divisorNeed;
        arrayN[k][1]=finding(divisorNeed);
        divisorNeed++;
    }
    return arrayN;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(message(2));
    int intervIn = intervIn();
    System.out.println(message(0)+'\n');
    int[][] arrayNRevis = doit(intervIn,2);
    System.out.println(message(1));
    for (int i=0;i<intervIn;i++){
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            System.out.print(arrayNRevis[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\b]");
    }
}
```

Output now (after almost 8 hours..):

> Please give the interval! [1-100] 100 Working...
>
> [1;1] [2;2] [3;4] [4;6] [5;16] [6;12] [7;64] [8;24] [9;36] [10;48]
>   [11;1024] [12;60] [13;4096] [14;192] [15;144] [16;120] [17;65536]
>   [18;180] [19;262144] [20;240] [21;576] [22;3072]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are not stuck on the 23rd number but it will take approx 120 hours to evaluate it. See http://oeis.org/A005179

Here is a APL NARS2000 workspace that speed up things a lot.
The first 100 take only 1/10 second.

```
      )WSID
C:\Users\Ab\AppData\Roaming\NARS2000\workspaces\combfactor

      )FNS
combfactor factors    listws     save                                                                                            

      )VARS
COMBFACTOR    DESCRIBE      DIV           RESULTSfor100                                                                       

    ∇ z ← combfactor n;f;p
[1]   f ← (⊂,n),factors n     ⋄ ⍝ find all factors combinations of n
[2]   p ← ⍸0π⍳¯2π32           ⋄ ⍝ The first 32 primes numbers
[3]   z ← ((⍴¨f)↑¨⊂⍟p)+.×¨f-1 ⋄ ⍝ give ratios of all combinations
[4]   z ← ∊¯1+((⌊/z)=z)/f     ⋄ ⍝ get the combination with minimum ratio
[5]   z ← (0x+(⍴z)↑p)×.*z     ⋄ ⍝ evaluate p_1^(f_1-1) * p_2^(f_2-1) * ... * p_n^(f_n-1)
    ∇

    ∇ z ← {fmax} factors n;f;d
[1]   :if 0 = ⎕NC 'fmax' ⋄ fmax ← 2*63 ⋄ :endif
[2]   z ← ⍬ ⋄ f ← ⌊fmax⌊n÷2
[3]   :while f ≥ 2
[4]     :if 0 = f∣n
[5]       d ← n÷f ⋄ :if d ∧.≤ f,fmax ⋄ z ,← ⊂f,d ⋄ :endif
[6]       z ,← f,¨f factors d
[7]     :endif ⋄ f -← 1
[8]   :endwhile
    ∇

      COMBFACTOR   
RESULTSfor100 ← ⍪(,¨⍳100),¨combfactor¨,¨⍳100 ⋄ ⍝ 0.1 second

      DESCRIBE     
DESCRIBE                                                                              
⍝ def factors(number, max_factor=sys.maxint):                                         
⍝     result = []                                                                     
⍝                                                                                     
⍝     factor = min(number / 2, max_factor)                                            
⍝     while factor >= 2:                                                              
⍝         if number % factor == 0:                                                    
⍝             divisor = number / factor                                               
⍝                                                                                     
⍝             if divisor <= factor and divisor <= max_factor:                         
⍝                 result.append([factor, divisor])                                    
⍝                                                                                     
⍝             result.extend([factor] + item for item in factors(divisor, factor))     
⍝                                                                                     
⍝         factor -= 1                                                                 
⍝                                                                                     
⍝     return result                                                                   
⍝                                                                                     
⍝ print factors(12) # -> [[6, 2], [4, 3], [3, 2, 2]]                                  
⍝ print factors(24) # -> [[12, 2], [8, 3], [6, 4], [6, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2, 2]]
⍝ print factors(157) # -> []                                                          

      DIV          
divisors←{z[⍋z←∊∘.×/1,¨(∪π⍵)*¨⍳¨∪⍦π⍵]}

      RESULTSfor100
   1 1                              
   2 2                              
   3 4                              
   4 6                              
   5 16                             
   6 12                             
   7 64                             
   8 24                             
   9 36                             
   10 48                            
   11 1024                          
   12 60                            
   13 4096                          
   14 192                           
   15 144                           
   16 120                           
   17 65536                         
   18 180                           
   19 262144                        
   20 240                           
   21 576                           
   22 3072                          
   23 4194304                       
   24 360                           
   25 1296                          
   26 12288                         
   27 900                           
   28 960                           
   29 268435456                     
   30 720                           
   31 1073741824                    
   32 840                           
   33 9216                          
   34 196608                        
   35 5184                          
   36 1260                          
   37 68719476736                   
   38 786432                        
   39 36864                         
   40 1680                          
   41 1099511627776                 
   42 2880                          
   43 4398046511104                 
   44 15360                         
   45 3600                          
   46 12582912                      
   47 70368744177664                
   48 2520                          
   49 46656                         
   50 6480                          
   51 589824                        
   52 61440                         
   53 4503599627370496              
   54 6300                          
   55 82944                         
   56 6720                          
   57 2359296                       
   58 805306368                     
   59 288230376151711744            
   60 5040                          
   61 1152921504606846976           
   62 3221225472                    
   63 14400                         
   64 7560                          
   65 331776                        
   66 46080                         
   67 73786976294838206464          
   68 983040                        
   69 37748736                      
   70 25920                         
   71 1180591620717411303424        
   72 10080                         
   73 4722366482869645213696        
   74 206158430208                  
   75 32400                         
   76 3932160                       
   77 746496                        
   78 184320                        
   79 302231454903657293676544      
   80 15120                         
   81 44100                         
   82 3298534883328                 
   83 4835703278458516698824704     
   84 20160                         
   85 5308416                       
   86 13194139533312                
   87 2415919104                    
   88 107520                        
   89 309485009821345068724781056   
   90 25200                         
   91 2985984                       
   92 62914560                      
   93 9663676416                    
   94 211106232532992               
   95 21233664                      
   96 27720                         
   97 79228162514264337593543950336 
   98 233280                        
   99 230400                        
   100 45360
```

And here is a C program that take **62 microsecond** !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MaxInt 0x7fffffffffffffff
#define ll long long

int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61,
                67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131};

ll minimums[16]; // contains minimum for each level

ll ipow(ll base, int exp) {
    ll result = 1;
    while (exp) {
        if (exp & 1)  result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;    base *= base;
    } return result;
}

ll factors(ll number, ll max_factor, int level) {
    ll result = MaxInt;
    ll factor = min(number / 2, max_factor);
    while (factor >= 2) {
        if (number % factor == 0) {
            ll divisor = number / factor;
            ll tempf = ipow(primes[level], factor-1);

            if (divisor <= factor && divisor <= max_factor) {
                ll tempd = ipow(primes[level+1], divisor-1);
                minimums[level] = min(minimums[level], tempf * tempd);
            }
            ll fct = factors(divisor, factor, level+1);
            if (fct < MaxInt)
                minimums[level] = min(minimums[level], tempf * fct);

            result = minimums[level];
            minimums[level+1] = MaxInt;
        }
        factor -= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

ll fact(int number) {
    for (int level = 0; level < 16; level++) minimums[level] = MaxInt;

    ll res = factors(number, MaxInt, 0);
    if (res < MaxInt) return res;
    else              return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N = 100;
    if (argc > 1) N = atoi(argv[1]);

    ll res[N];
    clock_t Start = clock();
    for(int n = 1; n <= 10000; n++)
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) res[i] = fact(i);
    printf("\n%0.6f second(s)\n", (clock() - Start)/1000.0/10000.0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        if (res[i] > 0)   printf("%d %lld\n", i, res[i]);
        else if (i > 64 ) printf("%d 2 power %d\n", i, i-1);
             else         printf("%d %lld\n", i, ipow(2, i-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every natural number `N` can be expressed as multiplication of prime numbers `p_i` raised to some powers `k_i` where `k_i >= 0`. So let's say you have number n equal to:

n = p_1^k_1 * p_2^k_2 * ... * p_z^k_z

this number will have `(k_1+1)*(k_2+1)*...*(k_z+1)` dividers, e.g.

18 = 2^1 * 3^2

and have (1+1)*(2+1) dividers or 6 dividers: 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18.

Prime numbers may be precomputed using sieve algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Then you may use dynamic programming to compute number of dividers of given number `n`. If `n = n_1 * p_i^k_i` (n can be divided by `p_i^k_i`), then number of dividers of n is number of dividers of n_1 * (k_i+1).

This should speed up computation of dividers counts.